# Using Javascript window.open and jQuery to submit a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, window.open, new-window

I would like to load yahoo.com in a new window using the window.open function. Then, fill in the search field and submit the search form using jQuery.

For some reason the following code doesn't work:

```
var yhooWin;
var yhooDoc;

function openYahooWindow() {
    yhooWin = window.open("http://yahoo.com","ywin","width=1050,height=750");
    yhooWin.focus();
}

openYahooWindow();
yhooDoc = yhooWin.document;

$(yhooDoc).ready(function () {
    $(yhooDoc).contents().find("#p_13838465-p").val("gangnam style");
    $(yhooDoc).contents().find(".searchsubmit").trigger("click");
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: By the way, p_13838465-p is the search field's id attribute. And the search button is the only thing with class "searchsubmit" ... in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access the contents of a different domain because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). Look at the error console, you will see the error message.

If you controlled the other domain, you could look into [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Another option is a serverside proxy. And another option is a service like [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) and make JSONP calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control a new window using another pages javascript.

For example:

Page1.html uses `window.open` to open yahoo.com

Page1.html can not take any action on yahoo.com